# Testing android apps in Vmware

Tags: android

I have installed Android studio and made an app. The Emulator is too slow.I want to know that if there is any way to integrate Android kitkat which i have installed in Vmware with android studio and use it for testing of apps.

Comment: The host OS is slow (at least, Windows is). A VM with a guest OS is even slower. Android uses Java, which is so slow (it's interpreted, so it uses another virtual machine). In an emulator (which is another virtual machine), it's even slower... So you have a Virtual machine in a virtual machine in a virtual machine. And cry for performances...

Comment: @Frank I don't think the OP is asking about running Android in VMWare (one layer of virtualisation) *instead of* the emulator (also one layer). VMWare is definitely faster, by default at least. Anurag yes this is possible but not easy and it's more difficult to simulate GPS, sensors, screen resolutions etc. You need to connect ADB to the instance in VMWare. I don't have full info but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: try GenyMotion, is faster than the stock emulator

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have an intel processor, try this https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

The nexus 5 emulator goes nearly as fast as the real machine!
And if not as fast, it'll boost it up a lot.

And, may be not in vmware but in virtual box using http://www.genymotion.com
Runs darn fast also.

Comment: Agreed this is definitely better than using vmware. See also: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm